# Pass argument with Vba excel in .onAction in excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I am Trying to pass the value i.e sArg with the onAction.But Im not able to do so.
I have tried like this: `"'btnT """ & sArg & """'"`  But this doesn't work.

```
For i = 3 To LastRow Step 1

    Set t2 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, LastCol + 3), Cells(i, LastCol + 3))
    Set btn2 = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t2.Left, t2.Top, t2.Width, t2.Height)
    sArg = CStr(i)
    With btn2

         .OnAction = "Sheet1.btnT"
      .Caption = "View " & i
      .Name = CStr(i)
    End With
Next i
```

Then the function is

```
Sub btnT(Text)
MsgBox Text
Exit Sub
```

Comment: After you add the control to the worksheet, you must use a separate function to capture the `Click` event. See [this explanation](https://www.homeandlearn.org/add_code_to_a_user_form_button.html)

Comment: AFAIK you can't (and usually don't need) pass argument to macro. In your case you want to pass the button name, so you just need to use [Caller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller) in the Sheet1.btnT procedure.

Comment: Caller gives me type mismatch error when I try to execute the script 2-3 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to enclose the single and possibly double quotes.

If the argument is numeric (eg 1), use

```
.OnAction = "'SubName 1'"
```

If the argument is a string then use

```
.OnAction = "'SubName ""SomeText""'"
```

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Arg As Variant
    Dim t2 As Range
    Dim btn2 As Button

    For i = 3 To 4 Step 1

        Set t2 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, LastCol + 3), Cells(i, LastCol + 3))
        Set btn2 = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t2.Left, t2.Top, t2.Width, t2.Height)
        Arg = i '<~~ adjust to suit your needs
        With btn2
            .Caption = "View " & i
            .Name = CStr(i)
            If IsNumeric(Arg) Then
                .OnAction = "'Sheet1.btnT " & Arg & "'"
            Else
                .OnAction = "'Sheet1.btnT """ & Arg & """'"
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub

Sub btnT(Arg As Variant)
    MsgBox Arg
End Sub
```